# qsort not working c program

Tags: c, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of names via qsort.

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b ) {

return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}


int main(void) {

int i;
char fileArr[] = {"inputbv", "inputa","inputzef",};

int stringLen = sizeof(fileArr) / sizeof(char *);

qsort(fileArr, stringLen, sizeof(char *), myCompare);

for (i=0; i<stringLen; ++i)
    printf("%d: %s\n", i, fileArr[i]);
}
```

This code doesn't print anything at the end. It just ends so it seems like it deletes the entries in the char array

Comment: Turn up your warnings. There are two emitted from this code that *directly* indicate the root problem.

Comment: You need `strcmp` in the compare function. Comparing the pointers might at best reverse them or leave them unchanged.

Comment: `int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b )` receives the addresses of array elements.  The arrays elements [should be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43215634/2410359)  `char *`, so the `a` in `myCompare()` should  convert to a `char **`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're missing a `*`:

```
char *fileArr[] = {"inputbv", "inputa","inputzef",};
```

This doesn't explain why you're not sorting correctly, which is a different issue, but it *does* explain why you're getting no output.  (A validating compiler, like `gcc -Wall`, would have told you that that declaration is invalid without that missing star.)

There are a number of other issues here, though.  First off, as one of the commenters alluded to, the `myCompare()` function is declared with the right type, but it doesn't quite do what you think it does:

```
int myCompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   ...
}
```

That's because `qsort()` passes the *address* to each chunk of data, not the chunk of data itself.  The chunks of data in this case are pointers to character arrays, so `qsort()` is going to pass pointers to pointers to your comparison function.  Those aren't single stars there; they're actually *two* stars in disguise.

Secondly, comparing pointers does you no good:  The pointers are, almost by definition, random values.  Your comparison function, as written, even if you corrected it for the number of `*`'s that are supposed to be there, would still be wrong:

```
/* Don't do this. */
return *(char **)a - *(char **)b;
```

That's literally more-or-less "sort by the random locations of these strings in memory," which doesn't help you at all for putting them in order.

The right thing to do is not to add yet another star (writing `**(char **)a - **(char **)b` literally means "compare the first characters against each other").  The right thing to do is invoke `strcmp()` to compare the two strings lexically:

```
int myCompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}
```

That's what you should be using.

Comment: Not my DV but as you said yourself: not an answer, but a very good comment.

Comment: I answered his specific question: "This code doesn't print anything." If he wanted to know why `qsort()` isn't doing what he expects, that's something else entirely.  (Interestingly, notice that he's not actually comparing the pointers, as you mentioned in your comment; he's sorting by the first characters, which are all identical: Unless he's lucky enough to have a stable sort under the hood, his code is likely more random than even sorting by pointers!)

Comment: There is no question, but the title is about `qsort`, and your comment could have been in your answer.

Comment: Well, yes, there's no sentence that ends in a "?"  But the last thing he talks about seems to be something like "why didn't I get any output," so I made a best guess as to what he was really asking.  _shrug_  You win some, you lose some.

Comment: So why not improve your answer?

Comment: Okay, okay, you badgered me into making it detailed and clear, even if nobody will ever actually see it >_>

Comment: Except the OP who will hopefully "accept" as the best answer.